# getopt utility in macOS is not respecting or not allowing space character while passed with a string argument

Tags: macos, getopt

getopt utility in macOS is not respecting or not allowing space character while passed with  a string argument.

Below is sample script

```
#!/bin/bash


TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "project:" -- -- "$@")

    [ $? -eq 0 ] || exit

    eval set --  "$TEMP"

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
             case "$1" in
                    --project) PROJECT="$2";;
                    --) shift;;
             esac
             shift;
    done

echo $PROJECT
```

Now when we run this script code in macOS (which has z-shell as command line interpreter)
we saw string part after space character is missing.

Script Run

```
./test.sh --project "testing app"
```

Result-coming

```
testing
```

Expected Output

```
testing app
```

While the same script code run in Linux/Unix OS is giving expected outcome either with bash shell or sh shell or zsh shell command line interpreters.

So why getopt is behaving like this in macOS for this piece of code?

Comment: From [BashFAQ on complex option parsing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing): "Traditional Unix systems have a program named `getopt`(1). This is a massively broken tool. You should never use it." and "Linux is so special that its developers decided to rewrite `getopt`. They made one that handles arguments with spaces in them, and empty arguments, and they did so by breaking compatibility with the Unix `getopt` program. But they did not change the name. So now there are two completely incompatible programs in the world, both named `getopt`, and one of them is a live minefield."

Comment: Why is this tagged zsh when you're explicitly using a bash script?

Comment: The */bin/bash* that ships with macOS is incredibly old and has many differences compared to newer versions that can bite you on the ass.. On my macOS 11.7.9 system the Bash version is v3.2. Compared to the current version which is something like v5.2. Beyond that, as Godon points out the `/usr/bin/getopt` program is borderline useless. You should use the bash `getopts` builtin instead. Alternatively, switch to a sane, non-POSIX shell, like Fish or Elvish.